# a class that modifies input data in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, class

please help me to make a class that modifies input data.
**For example** doubles the input number:

Main timeline:

```
var n:Number=47;
DoublerClass.double(n);
trace(n); //I want 94 here!
```

The class:

```
package{
class DoublerClass{

public static function double(input:Number){
 //a code that doubles input at my main timeline

 }  //end function

}
}
```

TweenLite or other same things do what I want. but I can't read that long codes or I may not understand them.

I appreciate your helps.

**EDIT

I dont want a class that **RETURNS** the multiplied value.
I want a class that directly modifies.

Comment: What is your goal here? Why do you want to do that in a function instead of simply using `*2`?

Comment: no need to shout, really. I had the suspicion that this is not your goal and asked for it. Could you please provide that information? What number do you want to modify and why? Provide some context.

Comment: possible duplicate of [as3 how to change a number by a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968898/as3-how-to-change-a-number-by-a-class)

Comment: Did you got the answer for what you have asked?

Comment: yes I got the main part of answer.I wanted to edit it to my desired answer but Null didn't want.I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To double a value, multiply it by 2.

```
package
{
   public class DoublerClass
   {
      public static function double(input:Number):Number
      {
         return 2 * input;
      }
   }
}
```

Used like so

```
var n:Number = 47;
DoublerClass.double(n);
trace(DoublerClass.double(n)); //I want 94 here!
```

That will return the value. You cannot pass `n` by reference to your function because it is of [a basic type and those are always passed by value in as3](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f56.html), that's why your function cannot modify the variable n on the timeline.

> In ActionScript 3.0, all arguments are passed by reference, because all values are stored as objects. However, **objects that belong to** the primitive data types, which includes Boolean, **Number**, int, uint, and String, have special operators that make them behave as if they were **passed by value**.

In order to do that, you'd have to pass a complex type, like an object to your function:

```
package
{
   public class DoublerClass
   {
      public static function double(input:Object):void
      {
         input.n *= 2;
      }
   }
}
```

which allowed you to do this

```
var object:Object = {n:47};
DoublerClass.double(object);
trace(object.n); //I want 94 here!
```

Comment: Your answer is great and is what I want.Thank you very very much and sorry again for my anger

Comment: The edited code works for me and is easier and better but if you don't want, no matter ;)

Answer (score 1):

in Main Timeline put this:

```
var d:DoublerClass=new DoublerClass();
var n:Number=d.double(47);
trace(n);//94
```

and in DoublerClass.as put this:

```
package{
    class DoublerClass{

public function DoublerClass():void{
}

public function double(input:Number):Number
{
 return input*2;

} 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is a good alternative, but there is actually a way to "do what you want":

Although you cannot modify `n` by reference from a function argument because primitives are passed by value, you can modify `n` by reference as a public property; instead of passing the value `n`, you pass the parent object (which is passed by reference) and the property name `"n"`:

```
function doubler(object:Object, property:String):void {
    object[property] *= 2;
}
```

Usage:

```
var n:Number = 47;
doubler(this, "n");
trace(n); // 94
```

This is how TweenLite does it.

Comment: Yes this is what I want. Thank you too!

Comment: @HITMAN do you see how this is different from what you suggested in the edit? `object.property` would not work here, also note that the function parameter `property` is of type `String`. [The brackets have many different uses, as you can see here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#array_access)

Comment: why would not work? if it would not work, why it works for me?

Answer (score 0):

The best answer based on Null's and Aaron's answers(I thank them).

```
public static function double(o:Object,n:Number){
  o.n*=2;}
```

at main timeline:

```
var n:number=47;  
DoublerClass.double(this,n);
trace(n); //94
```

Answer (score 0):

TweenLite is dealing with displayObject classes not with primitive data types.

Display object passing a reference to the function. Non primitive data types are have the ability to change the original variable value. Primitive data types have only access within the function only.

for example

```
//Timeline code
var xPos: Number = 100;
mc.x = 0;
DoublerClass.to(xPos, mc);

var _timer:Timer = new Timer(2000);
_timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimerAction);
_timer.start();

function onTimerAction(e:TimerEvent):void{
    trace("Primitive datatype value: " + xPos);
    trace("MovieClip x pos : " + mc.x);
}
```

DoublerClass with static function 'to'.

```
 package {
        import flash.display.MovieClip; 
        public class DoublerClass {     
            public static function to(xPos: Number, mc:MovieClip):void {
                //a code that doubles input;
                //it will not update the value because it is a primitive data type.
                xPos *= 2;
                //It will update the x position of the mc movieclip on the stage.
                mc.x = xPos;
            } //end function
        }
    }
```